Is this drywall repair acceptable after window replacement?
I recently had the windows replaced in my house and damage was done to the interior drywall in the process. The window company claims to have "fixed" some of the areas however the fix appears to be a layer of drywall compound or spackle which is not smooth and is clearly indented in areas. I have only paid half of the total amount due for the windows.
Is this acceptable work or should I demand a better fix?
Also, can damage of this extent be fixed with drywall compound alone?



All images are available at https://imgur.com/a/aUGmpWZ

This is a classic example of an opinion/contractual question. We don't know what you signed, and matters of quality are completely subjective. It's off topic here. See the [help]. If you were to revise to just ask about how repairs might be done it would be salvageable.

My $.02? They were given a tough situation to work with. You really should've had that paint finish sorted before they began (or omitted that obligation from their scope of work so you could do it later to your liking). 25 layers of chipped and peeling paint isn't a good basis for success.

That doesn't look like drywall compound, it looks like caulk.
Sorry, but the quality of their "fix" looks on-par with the surrounding areas. If you put a fresh coat of paint on everything then you will never notice it again.
It's weird that you have drywall for window casing instead of wood. It seems like it impeded the removal or installation of your windows because it made your casing a non-standard thickness.
Window replacement contractors typically concentrate on replacing the window, I doubt there is anything in the contract about "finishing" work.
The primary issue is that caulk is not sand-able so if you wanted to make it perfect then it could be a hassle.
Anyways, yes, drywall compound alone would have been a sufficient fix for your situation but it requires waiting for cure, sanding, re-applying, curing, sanding, priming, and finally painting. This is why they chose the easy route of applying caulk.
For what it's worth, I've done way worse things with caulk but usually took the time to smooth it out nicely.

The damage can be fixed with drywall compound.
However any repair should be unnoticeable.  The repairs that have been done are noticeable.  Tell the contractor that the repairs must be acceptable to you or they must have a drywall finisher do proper repairs before you will pay in full.
